# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 website takes 1.5 GB Memory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I developed an website in ASP.NET MVC 3.0 with NHibernate its deployed on server now my IT infra team informed that this site is taking upto 1.5 GB Memory (RAM) even when no user hits are their.

I asked them for server/IIS error to check wether any URL goes fail and also asked for an minimum benchmark of Memory for an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 website.

Can any one tell me what should i check for why this website is taking that much of memoey?

Or is it normal for ASP.NET MVC 3.0 WEbsite.

What is the minimum limit for such website.?

**Edited:**

IT Infra team gives me [This File](http://www.sendspace.com/file/8om18y).can any one one tell me whats the problem

Comment: Are you using a lot of Session data? Do you use some in memory caching? Are you running any initialization code or startup code when the app domain is loaded?

Comment: This can have many causes on of them being objects not being disposed and so on. have a look at this tool: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

Comment: @WouterdeKort i am using session data but its only for LoginAccountId (like 2001) an int. value.no memory caching.no extra init code.

Comment: @Syneryx ok will see through it.Thank you.

Comment: [Please Download this](http://www.sendspace.com/file/8om18y) and tell me whats the problem.